# ExPex fails with unicode-math. How to avoid the clash?

Tags: unicode-math, input-encodings, linguistics, expex

The following code fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{unicode-math}% Works without this

\begin{document}
\pex<ex>
\a<foo>\begingl
\gla  foo//
\glb  foo//
\glft foo//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

After removing `unicode-math` it works perfectly though. I need `unicode-math` only for using an OpenType font in math-mode. I didn't find any package other than `unicode-math` useful for this purpose. Is there any alternative available which I missed? Can I make `unicode-math` ignore the problematic command with some trickery? Note that I am using LuaLaTeX with fully updated TeX Live.

Comment: I have asked this question [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=6672) too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem as outlined in egreg's answer is that `unicode-math` defines a `\gla` command, and this assignment is done at the beginning of the document. The `\gla` command in ExPex is defined whenever the `glstyle` is set, so it is sufficient to simply reset the style using `\AtBeginDocument`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{unicode-math}% Works without this
\AtBeginDocument{\lingset{glstyle=wrap}}
\begin{document}

\pex<ex>
\a<foo>\begingl
\gla  foo//
\glb  foo//
\glft foo//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Works fantastically. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

`unicode-math` defines `\gla` to give U+2AA5 GREATER-THAN BESIDE LESS-THAN ⪥

If you don't need the glyph you can save its definition and restore it at the appropriate time

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}

\NewCommandCopy{\expexgla}{\gla}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy{\gla}{\expexgla}}

\begin{document}

\pex<ex>
\a<foo>
\begingl
\gla  foo//
\glb  foo//
\glft foo//
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

The clue was the message

```
! Missing character: There is no ⪥ (U+2AA5) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;.
```

and the corresponding line in `unicode-math-table.tex`

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02AA5}{\gla                      }{\mathrel}{greater-than beside less-than}%
```

[image]

As Alan Munn points out in comments, one can dispense with `\NewCommandCopy` and do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy{\gla}{\glw@gla}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pex<ex>
\a<foo>
\begingl
\gla  foo//
\glb  foo//
\glft foo//
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

One can also dispense With `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

```
\AtBeginDocument{\ExpandArgs{cc}\RenewCommandCopy{gla}{glw@gla}}
```

Note: in no place of `expex.tex` one finds where `\gla` is defined as `\glw@gla`. This is well hidden in

```
\definelabeltype{alpha}{labelgen=char,pexcnt=`a,labelformat=A.,
   fullrefformat=XA,labelalign=left,labelwidth=.72em}
```

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks a lot, I misinterpreted that it is an issue with the syntax. Thanks a lot. This is indeed very useful.

Comment: What is the use of `\AtBeginDocument` here if you are actually using it At Begin Document?

Comment: @Niranjan We must be certain that the instruction is executed after the `\AtBeginDocument` tokens executed by `unicode-math`.

Comment: Got it, what is the modern `hook`-alternative to this? IIRC these are old commands, right?

Comment: @Niranjan `\AddToHook{begindocument}{<code>}`

Comment: Thanks @mbert, will it be equivalent to egreg's code?

Comment: @Niranjan Yes, in source2e you'll find `\DeclareRobustCommand\AtBeginDocument{\AddToHook{begindocument}}`

Comment: @mbert It's exactly the same

Comment: @egreg Yes I know, I was just answering Niranjan's question. The lthooks doc does call `\AtBeginDocument` a legacy interface (though I'm aware "legacy" here does not mean "deprecated")

Comment: @mbert and which one should one use if they want to adhere to best practices?

Comment: Alternatively, without using the`\NewCommandCopy` command: `\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy{\gla}{\glw@gla}}`

Comment: @AlanMunn Which is well hidden.

Comment: @egreg Indeed. ExPex is a bit of a strange beast. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks, this one is shorter.

Comment: @egreg So well hidden that that's not where it is defined. :) That code defines a numbering scheme, not a gloss level.  It's created when the `glstyle` key is set, at which point the gloss levels are assigned using `\glw@assignlevels`, with the two built-in levels being `a` and `ft` stored in the levels list `\glw@levels`.